# Sticky headers appear on scroll even though table is toggled to invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header, tablesorter

I am a rookie programmer having some issues with a table that will eventually be part of a website that will include other graphics along with the table.  To avoid the potential for visual clutter, I would like the user to be able to toggle the table (which displays data from an external CSV file called "testdatastickyheadersissue.csv" here) on or off.  When the table is toggled on, the user should be able to sort the table andsee sticky headers when scrolling down the page.  The code below, which uses the tablesorter plugin and several of its widgets, works great for all of these features EXCEPT that the sticky headers are not disabled with the rest of the table when the table is toggled off, so the sticky headers still show up when scrolling down the page even when the rest of the table is invisible.  How can I hide the sticky headers when the table is toggled off?  I'm sure there is probably a simple fix for this, but I am stumped and would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> 
<meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
<meta name="dcterms.created" content="Thu, 14 Feb 2013 20:13:32 GMT">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<title>Test</title>

<style type="text/css">

 a {
   font-family:arial;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin:10px 0pt 15px;
font-size: 10pt;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
position:absolute;
top:1px;
left:1px}

/* CSS from 'style.css' - tables */
table.tablesorter {
font-family:arial;
background-color: #CDCDCD;
margin:10px 0pt 15px;
font-size: 8pt;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
position:absolute;
top:25px;
left:1px;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
background-color: #e6EEEE;
border: 1px solid #FFF;
font-size: 8pt;
padding: 4px;
}

table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
background-image: url(bg.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center right;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #3182BD;
}

table.tablesorter tbody td {
color: #3D3D3D;
padding: 4px;
background-color: #FFF;
vertical-align: top;
}

table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td {
background-color:#F0F0F6;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
background-image: url(asc.gif);
background-color: #9ECAE1;
}

table.tablesorter td.primary,
table.tablesorter tr.odd td.primary {
background-color: #99b3e6;
}
table.tablesorter tr.even td.primary {
background-color: #c2d1f0;
}

table.tablesorter td.secondary,
table.tablesorter tr.odd td.secondary {
background-color: #c2d1f0;
}
table.tablesorter tr.even td.secondary {
background-color: #d6e0f5;
}

table.tablesorter td.tertiary,
table.tablesorter tr.odd td.tertiary {
background-color: #d6e0f5;
}
table.tablesorter tr.even td.tertiary {
background-color: #ebf0fa;
}

/*table tr:hover {
background: #fff;
color: #ccc;
}*/


/*table tr:nth-child(even) {
background: #f0f8ff;
}

table th {
  background: #9ECAE1;
  }

table {
  border-width:0px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
}*/

</style>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.csvToTable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<table id="CSVTable" class="tablesorter" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">   </table>
<script>

$('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('testdatastickyheadersissue.csv', {
loadingImage: 'loading.gif', 
startLine: 1,
headers: ['id', 'name', 'pop11']
}).bind("loadComplete",function() { 
$(document).find('#CSVTable').tablesorter({
    headerTemplate : '{content}{icon}',
    widgets : ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'columns'], // include the widgets
    widgetOptions : {
    stickyHeaders : 'tablesorter-stickyHeader',
  // change the default column class names
  // primary is the first column sorted, secondary is the second, etc
  columns : ['primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary']
  // include thead when adding class names
  /*columns_thead : true,
  // include tfoot when adding class names
  columns_tfoot : true*/
}

});
});

function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("CSVTable");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "Show data table for counties";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "Hide data table for counties";
}
} 

function toggleVisibility() {
 document.getElementById("CSVTable").style.display = "";
 if(document.getElementById("CSVTable").style.visibility == "hidden" ) {
 document.getElementById("CSVTable").style.visibility = "visible";
 }
 else {
 document.getElementById("CSVTable").style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
} 

</script>  
<a href="javascript:toggleVisibility();">Click here to display/hide data table for counties.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of an external test CSV file:

```
id,name,pop11
1,A,1000
2,B,2000
3,C,3000
4,D,4000
5,E,5000
6,F,6000
7,G,7000
8,H,8000
9,I,9000
10,J,10000
11,K,11000
12,L,12000
13,M,13000
14,N,14000
15,O,15000
16,P,16000
17,Q,17000
18,R,18000
19,S,19000
20,T,20000
21,U,21000
22,V,22000
23,W,23000
24,X,24000
25,Y,25000
26,Z,26000
27,AA,27000
28,BB,28000
29,CC,29000
30,DD,30000
31,EE,31000
32,FF,32000
33,GG,33000
34,HH,34000
35,II,35000
36,JJ,36000
37,KK,37000
38,LL,38000
39,MM,39000
40,NN,40000
41,OO,41000
42,PP,42000
43,QQ,43000
44,RR,44000
45,SS,45000
46,TT,46000
47,UU,47000
48,VV,48000
49,WW,49000
50,XX,50000
51,YY,51000
52,ZZ,52000
53,AAA,53000
54,BBB,54000
55,CCC,55000
56,DDD,56000
57,EEE,57000
58,FFF,58000
59,GGG,59000
60,HHH,60000
61,III,61000
62,JJJ,62000
63,KKK,63000
64,LLL,64000
65,MMM,65000
66,NNN,66000
67,OOO,67000
68,PPP,68000
69,QQQ,69000
70,RRR,70000
71,SSS,71000
72,TTT,72000
73,UUU,73000
74,VVV,74000
75,WWW,75000
76,XXX,76000
77,YYY,77000
78,ZZZ,78000
```

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](http://i1299.photobucket.com/albums/ag70/geomapper123/ToggleTableStickyHeadersIssue_zps2be89c94.png) of the issue I'm encountering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to duplicate the issue you're describing... [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/473/))

Actually, hiding the table using `visiblilty: hidden` would cause this, but it looks like the table is being hidden with `display: none` and `visibility: hidden`.

Since you're using tablesorter, a jQuery plugin, I'm going to modify the code you're using to hide the table to use jQuery:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="toggle">Click here to display/hide data table for counties.</a>
```

Script

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.toggle').click(function(){
    var isHidden = $('#CSVTable').toggle().is(':hidden');
    $('#displayText').html( (isHidden ? 'Show' : 'Hide') + ' data table for counties');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested code, @Mottie.  I added a link to a screenshot above so you can see what is happening, at least on my computer.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: The screenshot doesn't tell me much, a demo of the issue would be much more helpful. Did the above code fix your problem?

Comment: So far, @Mottie, I haven't been successful with your code, but that is probably due to my lack of understanding.  I will keep trying and also see if I can create a demo.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I was finally able to solve the problem with your code, @Mottie.  Thank you very much!  I think my earlier lack of success was due to my not updating the relevant CSS.  Thanks again.